# SQLite3 PHP - взять больше одной строчки

Tags: php, sqlite3

Когда выполняю запрос

```
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;')->fetchArray();
```

В ответ получаю только одну(последнюю) запись в таблице, хотя хочу получить 5.
Как получить все 5 записей в PHP

Comment: Хотите сразу все, используйте fetchAll(). Если нужно обрабатывать каждую запись, цикл while по fetch(). Примеры тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sqlite-fetch-array.php Если у вас PDO, то там же ищите в разделе PDO.

Comment: мне говорит что fetchAll() и fetch() не существует

Comment: А что такое у вас $db? :) Откуда эта переменная берется? А то у вас может там самописный класс работы с базой, а не то что php предоставляет по умолчанию.

Comment: В общем мне самому удалось решить проблему, вот так
    $a = ($db->query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;'));
    while($entry = $a->fetchArray()){
        
        echo json_encode($entry);
        
    }

А $db это объект SQLite3 ;)

Comment: Так я вам про это и говорил по ссылке в примерах :Р